# Disabling access to some pages for mobile devices with Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, responsive

How can I block access to Post/New page for mobile devices with Rails? Do I need some sort of JS redirection?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check your client type from your header of the request. Moreover if you don't want to do that manually you can check this [gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser)

Answer (score 0):

There is no truly safe way to block all mobile devices!
You can check for the User-Agent in your controller and test if it's a mobile browser issuing the request.
Check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent for a list of UAs.

```
def is_mobile?
   request.user_agent == "mobile-ua-string"
end
```